# Student T-distribution in DAX

Tags: excel, distribution, dax

I would like to use the `Student T` cumulative distribution function & its inverse function in a measure related to a data table in `PivotTable` Fields.

Excel has a `T CDF` with `T.DIST` and its inverse with `T.INV`. However is it a more or less straightforward to use an equivalent in `DAX`?

I cannot currently find any answer to my question.

Thanks in advance for your insights!

Comment: I update my post because this is not the density function but the inverse of the cumulative one I do need to compute:

I would like to use the Student T cumulative distribution function & its inverse function in a measure related to a data table in PivotTable Fields.
Excel has a T CDF with T.DIST(..., ..., TRUE) and its inverse with T.INV. However is there any more or less straightforward way to use an equivalent in DAX?

Thanks in advance for your insights!